TypeScript type erasure at depth
While using the quite new tanstack router, i encountered some strange TypeScript behavior, one being the property to (from Router.navigate) being aliased to any when accessed using the Parameters<T> type built-in.
[src/main.tsx]

The second one happens at any route. I created a function with the following signature (full function here):
function artificialDelay<T>(ms = 5000): (val?: T) => Promise<T | undefined>

Using this function in the RouteOptions.beforeLoad like this:
createRootRoute({
    beforeLoad: artificialDelay(),
    component: () => (<></>),
});

Produces an gigantic error that can be summed up to the following:

Types of parameters val and opts are incompatible.
{
    search: RootSearchSchema;
    abortController: AbortController;
    preload: boolean;
    params: {};
    context: {};
    location: ParsedLocation<{}>;
    navigate: NavigateFn;
    buildLocation: BuildLocationFn<...>;
    cause: "preload" | /* 1 more */ | "stay";
}

is not assignable to type
{
    search: never;
    abortController: AbortController;
    preload: boolean;
    params: {};
    context: never;
    location: ParsedLocation<{}>;
    navigate: NavigateFn;
    buildLocation: BuildLocationFn<...>;
    cause: "preload" | /* 1 more */ | "stay";
}

Types of property search are incompatible.

Type RootSearchSchema is not assignable to type never.


You can see a minimal reproduction case here, based in the Quickstart (file-based) guide provided at the tanstack router docs page

Router.navigate, property to being aliased to any here

RouteOptions.beforeLoad opts.search being aliased to never here

artificialDelay function declaration here


As much as I wanted to, this seems to be a bug in TypeScript, not a bug in the tanstack router.
I tried multiple ways to get the parameters type, with all of them resulting in any being returned.
In the function generic, it shouldn't modify any of the parameters, returning the same type it received.

• Please [edit] the question so that any relevant code for a [mre] is included here as plaintext and not only as an external link (otherwise it doesn't count as a [mre]). • It also looks like you might want to tag this with "tanstack", if the question depends on it. If you think this is a TS bug that isn't a tanstack issue, then the best [mre] would be a from-scratch reproduction that doesn't need tanstack to show it. Since I don't know anything about tanstack I probably will just disengage unless that happens. Good luck!

@jcalz while I would like to include a minimal reproducible example in the question, but I think its a better choice to have a external link to the example, since it takes more than 10 files to set up, since its a vite project (index.html, package.json, package-lock.json, tsconfig.json, tsconfig.node.json, vite.config.ts and much more) so it would end up being cluttered. And as much as I wanted to prove my problem is related to tanstack library and not TypeScript, I could not prove it myself with a simpler example, hence my post explaining the problem using tanstack's library

I sincerely doubt that it takes 10 files to demonstrate a typing issue; in my experience this is almost never the case, unless the question is explicitly about the mechanics of exporting/importing modules, and that's not what you're asking. In any case, an external link is not sufficient for a Stack Overflow question and therefore this lacks the requisite debugging details. Your external code could disappear or change at any time. I'm going to vote to close this question; willing to retract if I see an appropriate edit.

I do agree with all you're saying, and would love to make an even simpler example, that does not require any libs or whatsoever. But, as I said before, I could not reproduce this behavior in other environments, and I do not have the background to know what and where to search to make this a better question.
